# Getting a list of Vnext builds for TFS 2017

Tags: build, vnext

I am trying to get a list of Vnext builds run using C# and BuildHttpClient but unable to retrieve them. However, the XAML Builds show up.

Does BuildHttpClient not recognize Vnext Builds? Some forums suggest using REST API for TFS but i am looking for sample piece of code.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I test at my side, it can get the Vnext build via BuildHttpClient.

1. Install [Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client
   package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/), then it will add necessary assemblies automatically.
2. Create project and try below code to get a list of the Vnext builds for TFS
   2017:

   ```
   using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi;

   using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;

   using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;

   using System;
   using System.Net;

   namespace GetBuild
   {
       class Program
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)

           {
               var u = new Uri("http://win-kev006:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/");
               VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain"))); 
               var connection = new VssConnection(u, c);
               var buildServer = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
               var builds = buildServer.GetBuildsAsync("LCTFVCScrum").Result; 
               for (int i = 0; i < builds.Count; i++)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(string.Format("  number: {0} -result: {1} - status: {2}", builds[i].BuildNumber, builds[i].Result.ToString(), builds[i].Status.ToString()));
               }

           }
       }
   }
   ```

The REST API is as below:

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version={version}
```

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#work-items

Comment: @Praveen Any update for the solution? have you resolved your issue?

Comment: I used the Github resource https://github.com/Microsoft/GetVSTSBuildUsage which uses the same concept. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: @Praveen However you can try following above steps to get the VNext builds if the Github resource not work, I tested above code at my side, it works correctly.

Comment: I could, but i don't have enough Reputation, so stackoverflow is not allowing me to mark it as helpful, Sorry.